# Select sum case in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have this problem: a query with `iif` (instead of `CASE` below) function works in MS Access doesn't work anymore in SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.quantity as q1,
    (SELECT sum(t2.quantity) where t2.id=t1.id FROM table2 as t2) as sumQuantity,
    (CASE sumQuantity IS NULL then 0 ELSE sumQuantity) as sumQuantityOk 
FROM 
    table1 as t1
```

The error is

> invalid sumQuantity column name

Without `CASE` (or with `iif` in MS ACCESS) the query is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
CASE sumQuantity IS NULL then 0 ELSE sumQuantity
```

with

```
CASE when sumQuantity IS NULL then 0 ELSE sumQuantity end
```

or use `coalesce` instead

```
coalesce(sumQuantity, 0)
```

Comment: I actually wrote as you said but I get that error. I think there's something with the SUM that doesn't work with CASE the way I think. I also tried COALESCE but same error. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ah my bad. Did not notice it. You can't use alias column names in the `select` clause or  `where` clause.

Comment: No, you're right, here I wrote from my memory but in the real code I wrote as you said. But I don't understand what do you mean by "you can't use alias column names...". I can use alias in the SELECT like this: "SELECT table.column as aliasColumn".

Comment: You make a subselect and name the result of that select `sumQuantity`. But now you can not use this name in the same `select` clause. Or in a `where` clause. You have to write that statement up again.

Comment: ah, ok. I thought the problem could be this. But how it works in MS Access ? Maybe because the database engine is different. Thanks again. I will sign the question as "Answered" hoping that it works with your answer.